# How to allow an attribute on an element with string content?

Tags: xml, parsing, xsd, xml-validation

I'm trying to write an XSD for the following XML:

```
  <users>
    <user id='u1'>A</user>
    <user id='u2'>B</user>
    <user id='u3'>C</user>
  </users>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:element name="users">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="user" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

But it returns errror:

> Element
>   '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element': The content is not valid.
>   Expected is (annotation?, ((simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key
>   | keyref)*))

The id attribute is the id of user.
Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to define an element with `simpleContent` (`xsd:string`) and an attribute in XSD:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="users">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="user" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
              <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
              </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

(Your error has nothing to do with `maxOccurs` being unbounded.  It had to do with the content model of your `user` element.)